# Windows is not trusting self-signed driver (using a custom self-signed CA)

Tags: c++, windows, certificate, driver, signing

For a private project I created a custom driver for a USB mass storage device. In my test environment (integrity checks disabled and test signing is enabled) everything works as expected.

Now, I've deployed a virtual machine with a basic Windows 10 installation.

Using OpenSSL I created a custom Certificate Authority and a codesigning certificate signed by the previously created ca.

Visual Studio happily signs my driver using the option "Sign Mode: Test Sign".

I copied the driver to the VM and installed the ca certificate. According to the "Digital Signatures" - Tab, within the driver's file properties, a signature exists and is trusted.

When I attempt to register the driver using OSR Loader I get an Error message saying that "Windows cannot verify the digital signature for this file".

My goal is to be able to install and run my driver in an "non-development" environment using a self-signed ca and certificate.

Note: I understand that I should buy a "official" code signing certificate to sign my driver but this project will not generate any money and will be only used by a hand full of my friends.

I created a VERY Basic driver that will use "DbgPrint" in order to print "DriverEntry called" and "DriverUnload called".

This driver will only be used as a reference to quickly test possible solutions.

[image: Image: My Visual Studio Settings for signing]

[image: Image: Digital Signatures (My CA is named "Driver", terrible I know)]

How I created my certificates:

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out codesign.key 2048
openssl req -new -key codesign.key -reqexts v3_req -out codesign.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 1826 -in codesign.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -extfile v3.cfg -set_serial 01 -out codesign.crt
openssl pkcs12 -export -out codesign.pfx -inkey codesign.key -in codesign.crt
```

The v3.cfg: https://pastebin.com/GWF9YVBa

Update:
I've tried to use the option "Production Sign" but my certificate cannot be used to sign non-tests signs.

Next: I switched back to test sign and enabled test signing on the vm using:
`bcdedit.exe -set TESTSIGNING ON` but still no success. :(

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NlaHr.jpg)

Comment: This might be because Windows on the VM does not trust "Driver", so it won't trust any certificates it issues.

Comment: Yes it could be... I actually tried one more thing: if I switch from Test Sign to Production sign my certificate is not selectable. Maybe production certificates behave differently.